# Are SQLite's s3db files portable from Windows to iOS / Android platforms?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I would like to use a Windows-based SQLite Administrator to work on my SQLite database. Is the DB file (s3db) portable to mobile platforms like iOS and Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQLite database file is just that, a file so it should work on any file system/OS regardless of where it was created.  The one exception to that would be something like encoding, but the beauty of SQLite is that it's actually just an abstraction on a flat file that allows you to preform most of the relational db functionality.  Also, because it's a standardized format, any client should work to read it as well (assuming both the creator and the reader conform to the specification).

Answer (score 2):

SQLite db files should be OS independant. Even file system independant. The files don't have encoding like UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 (or whatever the order of the numbers is, I always forget) because they're binary.

Have you tried?

Maybe the SQLite client matters. Maybe some clients leave signatures or something? The OS shouldn't matter.

Comment: i'm absolutely not sure about that, but isn't there bit endianness as another concern when encoding/decoding binary files?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely cross platform.  From the SQLite page:

> Stable Cross-Platform Database File
>
> The SQLite file format is
>   cross-platform. A database file
>   written on one machine can be copied
>   to and used on a different machine
>   with a different architecture.
>   Big-endian or little-endian, 32-bit or
>   64-bit does not matter. All machines
>   use the same file format. Furthermore,
>   the developers have pledged to keep
>   the file format stable and backwards
>   compatible, so newer versions of
>   SQLite can read and write older
>   database files. Most other SQL
>   database engines require you to dump
>   and restore the database when moving
>   from one platform to another and often
>   when upgrading to a newer version of
>   the software.

http://www.sqlite.org/different.html#onefile